# I´m getting the error, "atan2() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python, atan2

I´m new to programing so I have no idea what went wrong. please help

```
from math import atan2, pi
x = int(input("value of x"))
y = int(input("value of y"))
r = (x**2 + y**2) ** 0.5
ang = atan2(y/x)
print("Hypotenuse is", r, "angle is", ang)
```

Comment: when you call `atan2` you need to pass 2 arguments, `y/x` is 1 number, e.g. argument

Comment: Also, check the closing parenthesis on `atan2(`.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, there are 2 arctangent functions: `atan` is simply the inverse of `tan`; but `atan2` takes 2 arguments. In your case since you know both catheti, you could as well use the 2-argument function `atan2`:

```
ang = atan2(y, x)
```

Alternatively, you might write

```
ang = atan(y / x)
```

---

The rationale for `atan2` is that it works correctly even if `x` is 0; while with `atan(y / x)` a `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` would be raised.

Additionally, `atan` can only give an angle between -π/2 ... +π/2, whereas `atan2` knows the signs of both `y` and `x`, and thus can know which of the 4 quadrants the value falls to; its value ranges from -π to +π. Though, of course you wouldn't have a triangle with negative width or height...

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that error is that `atan2` requires two arguments.  Observe:

```
>>> from math import atan, atan2
>>> atan(2)
1.1071487177940904
>>> atan2(4, 2)
1.1071487177940904
```

Note that `atan(y/x)` does not work if `x` is zero but  `atan2(y, x)`  will continue to work just fine:

```
>>> atan(4/0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>> atan2(4, 0)
1.5707963267948966
```